# How to distinguish for EditText's between pasting into or setting per setText()?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have an EditText what I populate via

```
editText.setText(content)
```

The reason this is an EditText and not a TextView is because I also want to paste stuff (later when user is operating the app) in it or manually type in it, if applicable.

But I have to

- reset a flag if editText set via `setText()`
- and nothing if pasted by user

**How can I distinguish how a EditText was populated?** `addTextChangedListener()`'s callbacks are triggered in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Listener Class:

```
public interface GoEditTextListener {
void onUpdate();
}
```

Custom Edittext

```
public class GoEditText extends EditText
{
    ArrayList<GoEditTextListener> listeners;

    public GoEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public GoEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public GoEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addListener(GoEditTextListener listener) {
        try {
            listeners.add(listener);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Here you can catch paste, copy and cut events
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
        boolean consumed = super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
        switch (id){
            case android.R.id.cut:
                onTextCut();
                break;
            case android.R.id.paste:
                onTextPaste();
                break;
            case android.R.id.copy:
                onTextCopy();
        }
        return consumed;
    }

    public void onTextCut(){
    }

    public void onTextCopy(){
    }

    /**
     * adding listener for Paste for example
     */
    public void onTextPaste(){
        for (GoEditTextListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

xml

```
<com.yourname.project.GoEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"/>
```

Code

```
private GoEditText editText1;

editText1 = (GoEditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            editText1.addListener(new GoEditTextListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUpdate() {
//here do what you want when text Pasted
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply extend `EditText`, include the flag, and override `setText`:

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {
    boolean fromSetText;

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {

        super.setText(text);
        fromSetText = true;
    }
}
```

You can define your own setters/getters and constructors based on your requirements.

Comment: Isn't `setText()` not called during 'paste'-ings?

Comment: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.exmaple.demo.ui.shared.MyEditText`

Comment: You need to define the constructors.